# How to select a field whose selector id is dynamic in behavior in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have an ID: s2id_autogen4_search in which the number after autogen keeps changing due to which I am not able to select the ID. Is there a way to select the element in selenium

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and post relevant HTML & your code trail?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element((By.XPATH,"//[starts-with(@id,'s2id_autogen')]"))
```

You can use starts with to find an id.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the neighbor answer, you can try also:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'s2id_autogen')]")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//<tag>[contains(@id,'s2id_autogen')]")
```

where 'tag' of the element

to make selector more unique, use 'and' like that:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("[contains(@id,'s2id_autogen') and contains(@id,'search')]")
```

or with starts_with:

```
driver.find_element((By.XPATH,"//*[starts-with(@id,'s2id_autogen') and contains(@id,'_search')]"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but there is another element on the same page which has s2id_autogen. Is there a way I can include s2id_autogen_search as well?

Comment: @notfluffy you can use find_elements_by_xpath()[number_of_the_element] it always have number in the list. You can as well use additional attribute value, like:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//<tag>[contains(@id,'s2id_autogen') and @class='class_element']")

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element((By.XPATH,"//*[starts-with(@id,'s2id_autogen') and contains(@id,'_search')]"))
```

use both start with and contains using "and"